# Cardinality of Binary String

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is the set of all infinite binary strings. The question is what is the cardinality of $B$ that contains all the strings in $A$ that have finite number of '1' (i.e "ones").

I started by looking at the cardinality of $A$ which is $ |{0,1}|^\mathbb{N} $ meaning all the functions from $N$ to $\{0,1\}$ and it easy to see that the cardinality of $A$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$ But I don't know how to proceed.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ are there?

Comment: @BrianO: That is another way to view the question, but I don't think it's any easier in this case. However it brings the interesting viewpoint that finite subsets of an infinite set $S$ can be understood as sets of size 1, 2, 3, ... and then one would need (want) $\#(S^1) + \#(S^2) + \#(S^3) + \cdots = \#(S)$. My answer wouldn't work for uncountable $S$. (And did you see my questions to you in the chat-room?)

Comment: @user21820 Thank you for your answer , i dont know what is the "chat-room" and how do I enter it. .

Comment: Noam, my comment was meant for BrianO. Though the first part is also relevant to this question but not as easy as the approach in my answer.

Comment: @user21820 Ok , thank you

Comment: @user21820 No didn't see your questions, sorry, been jammed up with other things. I'll check.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If a binary string has finitely many ones, it has a **final** one. Now how many binary strings have a final one at position $n$? Then you can 'sum' over all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Well I think that there are {0,1}^n meaning as many functions as from a set of size n to the set {0,1} but what do you mean by "'sum' over all natural numbers"?

Comment: @Noam: "as many functions as from a set of size n to the set {0,1}".. exactly how many is that? And you want number of binary strings with finitely many ones, which is equal to the number of binary strings with a final one, which splits into many groups, one group for the final one at position $n$. So of course the total is the 'sum'. It's not a proper sum in the usual sense because it does not converge to a real number, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I think that for every string with a final one at position n there are 2^(n-1) different Strings.. But the sum concept is still not clear to me - should I sum 2^0 + 2^1 +...... 2^n ?

Comment: @Noam: Right, assuming you start from position $1$. And the 'sum' is the right idea, but clearly it's not finite, so neither is the set you're asking about. But then is it countably infinite? Are you able to assign a unique natural number to each element by running through each group one at a time?

Comment: Well no , I don't think I can or atleast I can't see how. I know that the set is infinite and I thought of trying to show a bijection between P(N) to those Strings and then conclude that the cardinality is Aleph but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: @Noam: I know you tried that (it's in your question). What I was asking is whether or not you can find a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and those strings. You said that group $n$ had $2^{n-1}$ elements, so can you number **all** the strings by going through each group one by one?

Comment: No , I can't. Sorry if that disappoint you.

Comment: I think I got it. I will split B in to b1,b2,b3,b4 (bi - all sets with i number of oners)  and show a bijection from N to b1 and from NxN to b2 and so on... from there it is easy to see that cardinality of b1,....bn is aleph0 and then the union of all b1,.....bn is also aleph0 and B is actually the union of all b1,.....bn so B cardinalty is aleph0 and done.

Comment: @Noam: That will work too (it's the method BrianO and I gave in the other comments), but it's actually harder in this case! You see, each group here (group $n$ is the set of strings with final one at position $n$) is finite, so you can number them group by group. Just assign unique natural numbers to all strings in group 1, then to all strings in group 2 (without reusing previously assigned numbers), and so on. Clearly you will never run out of natural numbers because each group is finite, and so you'll finish assigning every string a natural number.

Comment: @Noam: Why I say that the alternative method is harder is that it depends on knowing that $|\mathbb{N}^2| = |\mathbb{N}|$, which is **not easier** than the original question because the simplest proof of it requires the exact same technique...